# Get the base URL in Magento system.xml file in comment tag

Tags: system.xml, base-url

In the below `<comment>` 
`<a href='admin/shipper_method'>` tag, 
It's not redirecting to the correct page..

```
<allowedmethods translate="label">
   <label>Allowed Methods</label>
   <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
   <sort_order>30</sort_order>
   <source_model>ultimate_shipper/resource_method_collection</source_model>
   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
   <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
   <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
   <comment><![CDATA[<a href='admin/shipper_method'>Add Custom Method</a>. Example Comment.]]></comment>
</allowedmethods>
```

What I need is like this,

`<a href='http://192.168.1.193/madison/admin/shipper_method'>Add Custom Method</a>`

or

`<a href='http://example.com/admin/shipper_method'>Add Custom Method</a>`

In front-end...

For that, What can I put in the `system.xml`?

For example:
`<comment><![CDATA[<a href='{{baseURL}}admin/shipper_method'>Add Custom Method</a>. Example Comment.]]></comment>`

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686457/how-to-set-link-is-magegetbaseurl-for-breadcrumbs-in-layout/14576428#14576428

Comment: Note: The Example I have Given Doesn't Works..

Comment: i don't think you can achieve this in comment

Comment: @Minesh any alternate ways..?

Comment: check Marius's answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a a model to generate the comment for a config field:
Something like this:

```
<comment>
    <model>ultimate_shipper/adminhtml_allowedmethods_comment</model>
</comment>
```

then you need to create the file:  `Ultimate/Shipper/Model/Adminhtml/Allowedmethods/Comment.php` with this content:

```
<?php
class Ultimate_Shipper_Model_Adminhtml_Allowedmethods_Comment
{
    public function getCommentText()
    {
        $text = Mage::helper('ultimate_shipper')->__('Add Custom Method');
        return '<a href="'.Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/shipper_method').'">'.$text.'</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: It Gives `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Shipper_Method_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/madison/app/Mage.php on line 547`.. What has to mentioned in the helper..? and how..?

Comment: You need to declare the helper alias of your module. Or change the helper alias to `core` in `Mage::helper`call.

Comment: ! It gives an error when redirecting, It gives the url `<a href='http://192.168.1.193/madison/index.php/admin/shipper_method'>Add Custom Method</a>` But when clicked it redirects to the dashboard page.. Why it's happening..? Is there are any other way to display the right page. I found the `Key` was changing..

Comment: sorry. my bad. check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Add into system.xml file**

```
<field id="row_payment_us_free" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" canRestore="1">
    <label>Payment US Free</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
    <comment><model>VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\SystemConfigComment</model></comment>
</field>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**SystemConfigComment.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class SystemConfigComment implements \Magento\Config\Model\Config\CommentInterface
{
    protected $urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlInterface
    ) {
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    }

    public function getCommentText($elementValue)
    {
        $url = $this->urlInterface->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/payment');

        return 'Require to enable <a href="' .$url . '#row_payment_us_free" target="_blank">Zero Subtotal Checkout</a>payment method for Zero Subtotal order.';
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***